# Ansible: Transforming list to dictionary with items2dict

Tags: python, ansible

Given the following list:

```
fruits:
  - fruit: apple
    color: red
    texture: crunchy
    shape: round
  - fruit: grapefruit
    color: yellow
    taste: sour
  - fruit: pear
    color: yellow
```

How would I use the items2dict filter to change to a dictionary (below)?
Problem is there is multiple, and a variable amount of values.

```
"{{ fruits | items2dict(key_name='fruit', value_name='??????') }}
```

Desired result:

```
fruits:
  - apple:
      color: red
      texture: crunchy
      shape: round
  - grapefruit:
      color: yellow
      taste: sour
  - pear:
      color: yellow
```

I can't seem to find how here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fruits2: "{{ fruits2|default([]) + [{ item['fruit']: value }]}}"
      loop: "{{ fruits }}"
      vars:
        keys: "{{ item.keys()|difference(['fruit']) }}"
        vals: "{{ keys|map('extract', item)|list }}"
        value: "{{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fruits2:
  - apple:
      color: red
      shape: round
      texture: crunchy
  - grapefruit:
      color: yellow
      taste: sour
  - pear:
      color: yellow
```

---

A dictionary, instead of a list, can be created by simply changing the concatenation of the lists to the combination of the dictionaries e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fruits3: "{{ fruits3|default({})|combine({ item['fruit']: value }) }}"
      loop: "{{ fruits }}"
      vars:
        keys: "{{ item.keys()|difference(['fruit']) }}"
        vals: "{{ keys|map('extract', item)|list }}"
        value: "{{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fruits3:
    apple:
      color: red
      shape: round
      texture: crunchy
    grapefruit:
      color: yellow
      taste: sour
    pear:
      color: yellow
```

---

[items2dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries) can be used to select 2 attributes only (`key_name` and `value_name`) e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fruits4: "{{ fruits|items2dict(key_name='fruit', value_name='color') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fruits4:
    apple: red
    grapefruit: yellow
    pear: yellow
```

A list (desired result) can't be created by `items2dict`. `items2dict` returns a dictionary.

---

`items2dict` will fail if the attribute is missing e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        fruits5: "{{ fruits|items2dict(key_name='fruit', value_name='taste') }}"
```

fails

```yaml
The error was: KeyError: 'taste'
```

Comment: When creating a list (fruits3), an individual dictionary item can be referenced like so:

"{{ fruits3.apple.texture }}"

will return

"crunchy"

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do something like:

```
- name: bla
  set_fact:
    res: "{{ res | default({}) | combine({ item['fruit']: item }) }}"
  loop: "{{ fruits }}"
```

Comment: Cheers, clean and straight forward! To merge and update any existing values in "res" with each "item" in "fruit", add list_merge='append_rp', recursive=true as two argument to combine.

Answer (score 0):

The `items2dict()` function is not appropriate for your case, but you may use this simple approach instead:

```
rows = """\
fruits:
  - fruit: apple
    color: red
    texture: crunchy
    shape: round
  - fruit: grapefruit
    color: yellow
    taste: sour
  - fruit: pear
    color: yellow"""

rows_changed = "\n".join([2*" " + row if row.startswith(4*" ") else row 
                             for row in rows.split("\n")])
print(rows_changed)
```

---

*The explanation:*

1. `rows.split("\n")` creates a list of rows from the `rows` multi-line string,
2. the expression `2*" " + row if row.startswith(4*" ") else row` within `[]` (the list comprehension) then indents rows starting with 4-space indent by another 2-space indent,
3. `"\n".join()` convert that (modified) list of rows back to the multi-line string.

---

*The output:*

> ```
> fruits:
>   - fruit: apple
>       color: red
>       texture: crunchy
>       shape: round
>   - fruit: grapefruit
>       color: yellow
>       taste: sour
>   - fruit: pear
>       color: yellow
> ```